# How a AltBeacon transmitter can keep sending signal with phone locked in Android?

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon

I'm using AltBeacon Android Library and trying to make a Beacon Transmitter. I put the AltBeacon's sample code inside my Activity "onCreate" and works fine. However, when the app loose focus, or is closed, or phone is locked, the transmitter stops emitting signal. Its possible to keep emitting signal in these cases ?

Answer (score 0):

On the Android platform, **beacon transmission (and Bluetooth LE advertising in general) continues even if an app is in the background.**  If you aren't seeing this happening, there are two possible explanations:

- Something specific to your app is stopping transmission when it transitions to the background.  It might not be obvious -- it could even be garbage collection that causes this.  You'd have to post your code to get help with this possibility.
- There is a customization on your device's Android ROM that disables this behavior.  You could see if this is true independent if your app by transmitting with an app that is known to continue working in the background on typical Android devices.  The [Locate App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) (based on the same library) is one to try.